# Centering a data frame, function error

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to center a data frame column by column. I came up with this, but it is giving me all kinds of errors:

```
centered_out<-apply(out,2 function(col){
  csum<-colSums(col)
  lapply(col,function(x)
    x-csum  
  )
  })
```

example data:

```
1
2
1
2
4
```

calculation (mean=5):

```
-4
-3
-4
-3
-1
```

my end goal is the get all of the data in the data frame centered like above.

Comment: You code is too complicated. Simple `centered_out <- apply(out,2,function(col) {col-mean(col)})` should make the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `scale` function. Example:

```
scale(mtcars,scale=FALSE)
```

You can also use `sweep`. See `??sweep`.